# No Framework found while implementing firebase in Libgdx in iOS module

Tags: ios, firebase, libgdx, cocoapods, robovm

I am trying to add FCM in iOS module of Libgdx project for which i have found [robobpods](https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm-robopods/tree/master/firebase/) to install firebase pod. I followed guide provided in this library but while build project it says no firebase framework found.

```html
[ERROR] 22:53:12.055 ld: framework not found FirebaseMessaging
[ERROR] 22:53:12.068 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[ERROR] Couldn't compile app
org.apache.commons.exec.ExecuteException: Command '[/Users/amar/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++, -o,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alt pods bindings are for more recent version of firebase.
In general you should copy
Firebase/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseMessaging.xcframework/ios-i386_x86_64-simulator/FirebaseMessaging.framework to folder sim_libs (or what ever you like)
then add

```
<frameworkPaths>

<path variant="device">arm_libs</path>

<path variant="simulator">sim_libs</path>
</frameworkPaths>
```

to robovm.xml also you should copyios-armv7_arm64variants toarm_libs` to run on device